# How to sum the price grouped by some variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The first list in image shows what I have achieved after loop. Now I want sum of "pay" grouped by "organizationid" as shown in the second list.
I only need the second list to be saved in database but could not achieve it with JQuery.

How can I get the sum grouped by organizationid using jquery?

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Why were you trying to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and aggregate them to another object:

```
var input = [
    { oId: 1, pay: 10 }, 
    { oId: 1, pay: 10 }, 
    { oId: 2, pay: 20 }, 
    { oId: 2, pay: 20 }, 
    { oId: 3, pay: 30 }
];

var result = {} ;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var rec = input[i];

    if(result.hasOwnProperty(rec.oId))
        result[rec.oId] += rec.pay;
    else
        result[rec.oId] = rec.pay;
}

return result;
```

Comment: Even if the OP has not provided any code, this is a good answer and does not deserve donwvotes

Comment: There is some minor problem with it: when you run it you will have {1: Nan, 2:Nan..}

Comment: @lukbl cheers! I've added `hasOwnProperty` check so that the properties init correctly :-)